# ANdroid: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, locationmanager

I am creating a directional application in android . that why i have to get the location from the android device here is my code when i run this code it give me Exception at these line

```
curlat = location.getLatitude();
curlng = location.getLongitude();
```

This is whole function

```
public void newlocation(Context context) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the location provider
    criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE); // default
    // user defines the criteria
    criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
    // get the best provider depending on the criteria
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    // the last known location of this provider

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    mylistener = new MyLocationListener();
    if (location != null) {
        mylistener.onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
        // leads to the settings because there is no last known location
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    // location updates: at least 1 meter and 200millsecs change
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 200, 1, mylistener);
    // String a=""+location.getLatitude();
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a, 222).show();

    curlat = location.getLatitude();
    curlng = location.getLongitude();
    Log.d("************", "1111111111111111");
    new GetAddressTask(this).execute(location);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting null object of location so before access the lat and log make a null point check

```
if(location!= null){
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
double longitude = location.getLongitude();}
```